Kotlin coroutines - dispatcher switch doesn't work
I have this code:
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (openGraphParser != null && isActive) {
            Logger.info("Loading OpenGraph data for $link")
            val content = openGraphParser.getContents(link, messageText)
            Logger.info("OpenGraph data for $link received")

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Logger.info("Showing OpenGraph data for $link")
                onOgDataReceived(content)
            }
        }

And I don't see the log: "Showing OpenGraph data for $link". The code inside "withContext(...)" is simply not called. Why? Can anybody explain it to me? The last log is "OpenGraph data for $link received". If I change it to
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (openGraphParser != null && isActive) {
            Logger.info("Loading OpenGraph data for $link")
            val content = openGraphParser.getContents(link, messageText)
            Logger.info("OpenGraph data for $link received")

            ogDataContent?.ogDataLayout?.get()?.post {
                Logger.info("Showing OpenGraph data for $link")
                onOgDataReceived(content)
            }
        }
    }

than everything works fine with post within view.

Are you using kotlin multiplatform?

Please reduce your code to a [mre] so that we can execute it too.

No, it's not multiplatform. Code reducing is a little complicated. Before switching to main thread there is network query

In my opinion there is two case may occur

coroutine is running within a valid coroutineScope. If coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) is not properly scoped and the coroutine is canceled or completed before reaching the withContext call, the code inside may not execute.

When using withContext ensure that you are correctly switching to the main dispatcher. If there are any issues with the main dispatcher (like if it isn't set up correctly in your environment), this could cause your code to fail silently.


so I would suggest you:
   coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    if (openGraphParser != null && isActive) {
        Logger.info("Loading OpenGraph data for $link")
        try {
            val content = openGraphParser.getContents(link, messageText)
            Logger.info("OpenGraph data for $link received")

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Logger.info("Showing OpenGraph data for $link")
                onOgDataReceived(content)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.error("Error fetching OpenGraph data: ${e.message}")
        }
    } else {
        Logger.warn("OpenGraph parser is null or coroutine is not active")
    }
   }


It seems that an exception occurs in your coroutine scope (Maybe a null pointer exception!). You cannot see it because you did not use CoroutineExceptionHandler, and the scope eats the exception. The solution is to provide CoroutineExceptionHandler to your scope like so :
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _: CoroutineContext, throwable: Throwable ->
    throwable.printStackTrace()
}
coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler) {
    if (openGraphParser != null && isActive) {
        Logger.info("Loading OpenGraph data for $link")
        val content = openGraphParser.getContents(link, messageText)
        Logger.info("OpenGraph data for $link received")
        
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Logger.info("Showing OpenGraph data for $link")
            onOgDataReceived(content)
        }
    }
}

Then check your logcat to see the exception log.
